# How reliable is AsymptoticIntegrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions, asymptotics

In new mathematica 12 there is a new function `AsymptoticIntegrate`. However, it seems that it gives me incorrect results in some cases. To be completely honest, it is hard to tell if those results are indeed incorrect because the mathematical expressions are quite complex. So, I'm interested if someone else from this website has had similar experience? I want to know with what degree of certainty can I believe that the mathematica output in this case is indeed correct, having in mind that this function is quite new.

I do know that there are some examples where mathematica gives the wrong
result, that's why I'm posting this question in the first place.

For example:

```
    Integrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$. However

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, t}, {t, Infinity, 1}]
```

gives `BesselJ[0, 2 t] Sin[t]` which is zero in the limit $t\to \infty$.

But these two examples should give the same result in the limit $t \to \infty$, right?

Comment: You should post one or two examples. Otherwise there is nothing concrete to analyze and respond to.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I added an example now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The improper integral `Integrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` is not found as the limit of `Integrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0]` as `t` tends to infinity in Mathematica since the latter command returns the input.

Comment: Also the command `Series[Integrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, t}], {t, Infinity, 1},
  Assumptions -> t > 0]` returns the input.

Comment: @user64494 The command `Integrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0]` return the input because mathematica cannot find the indefinite integral of that function. But that does not mean we cannot find its asymptotic behavior. As for your other comment, it returns the input for  `Series` command because (the way you wrote it) it needs to calculate the integral first, and then find its series expansion. 

That's why they introduced AsymptoticIntegrate in mathematica 12, which was not present in the previous editions of mathematica.

Comment: @RedGiant: In many cases `AsymptoticIntegrate` works as `Series@Integrate`.

Comment: @user64494 I agree. But those are only the cases when mathematica actually can perform indefinite integral. Otherwise it has to use some other approach.

Comment: @RedGlant: A quit good asymptotics for the integral `Integrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, t}]` is  `1/Sqrt[3] - (-(Cos[t]/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t])) - Sin[t]/(
   2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]))` as  `t` approaches infinity along the real axis, This  can be found with help of Mathematica.

Comment: @user64494  That result is nice. How did you get that? I'm more interested in the method that this specific example because I want to use it in different examples.

Comment: @RedGlant: A key point is `Normal[Series[
  Integrate[
   Normal[Series[-BesselJ[0, 2 s] Cos[s], {s, Infinity, 2}]], {s, t, 
    Infinity}, Assumptions -> t > 0], {t, Infinity, 1}]]`. I came to it trying   L'Hospitale's rule.

Comment: @user64494 Oh I see, thank you. Although when I plug your code into mathematica I obtain two more terms, which can be simplified using `FullSimolify`. Those two terms are $\frac{\sin (3 t)-\cos (3 t)}{6 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{t}}$. They kinda ruin the final result, the one you presented was much better (I know approximately what I'm supposed to get ).

Comment: @RedGlant: Your words do not correspond to reality. I cutted the output of `Normal[Series[   Integrate[    Normal[Series[-BesselJ[0, 2 s] Cos[s], {s, Infinity, 2}]], {s, t,      Infinity}, Assumptions -> t > 0], {t, Infinity, 1}]]` for simplicity, remaining the two leading terms.

Comment: @user64494 But all of these terms $\frac{3 \sin (t)+\sin (3 t)-3 \cos (t)-\cos (3 t)}{6 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{t}}$ are leading, aren't they? All of them behave as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ when $t\to \infty$

Comment: @RedGlant: You are right. Thank you for your notice. The leading terms are `Cos[t]/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]) - Cos[3 t]/(
 6 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]) + Sin[t]/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]) + 
 Sin[3 t]/(6 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t])`. It does not change the matter.

Comment: See the result of `Plot[{NIntegrate[Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, t}] - 1/Sqrt[3], 
  NIntegrate[
    Cos[x]*BesselJ[0, 2 x], {x, 0, 
     t}] - (1/
      Sqrt[3] - (Cos[t]/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]) - 
       Cos[3 t]/(6 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]) + 
       Sin[t]/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t]) + 
       Sin[3 t]/(6 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[t])))}, {t, 1000, 1010}]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117960/discussion-between-redgiant-and-user64494).